# Using a Variable in WP Download Manager Shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, shortcode

sorry if this isn't allowed here as it is related to Wordpress but it is PHP related.

I am using a Wordpress plugin called Pods - Custom Content Types and Fields and WP Download Manager.

In PODs I have created a POD that has a user select from  drop down a post from WP Downloads Manager. This is set as `resource_link_protected`. This is all fine and I can display the Download by using magic tags such as

```
echo '{@resource_link_protected.ID}'; //DISPLAYS 1554 FOR EXAMPLE
```

This will display the ID number of the selected download. Works Great! However, I need to uses this value in a shortcode So I use:

```
$linkid = '{@resource_link_protected.ID}';
echo do_shortcode("[wpdm_package id='$linkid' template='link-template-button']");
```

This doesn't work, if I echo `$linkid` it displays 1554 as per my example above. If I replace `$linkid` with 1554 in the shortcode, it works and displays a button.

Why when I create a variable (`$linkid = '{@resource_link_protected.ID}';`) does it work to echo etc. but then doesn't work inside the shortcode even though `$linkid = '1554'` would?

Comment: Try using `do_magic_tags()` like this `$linkid = do_magic_tags('{@resource_link_protected.ID}');`

Comment: There isn't a function for `do_magic_tags()` and I can't find any documentation of PODs website

Comment: https://docs.pods.io/code/pods/do-magic-tags/

Comment: I am using it inside a POD template and I get an error `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function do_magic_tags()`

Comment: Ok, seems to have solved it, the issue was with the `do_shortcode()`, if I just do `$linkid = '{@resource_link_protected.ID}'; echo '[wpdm_package id='.$linkid.' template="link-template-button"]';` it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$linkid = '{@resource_link_protected.ID}'; 
echo '[wpdm_package id='.$linkid.' template="link-template-button"]';
```

Comment: Your answer contains code without explanation. It's better to include details about *how* your answer answers the question.